# preg replace in jquery removing dots

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an URL that looks like this :

```
http://www.blabla.com/../images/wow.jpg
```

I would like to remove the double dots and slash and I thought I could do it this way :

```
var img = IMAGE_PATH + url;
var image = img.replace(/\.{2}\//,'');
```

But that's not doing anything. Could someone please tell me how I could do this in jquery ?

Thanks

Comment: What does `IMAGE_PATH` hold? See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jdue2eqc/) - it works if the `url` contains one `../`. If you have more, add `/g`: `.replace(/\.{2}\//g,'')`

Comment: IMAGE_PATH holds 'http://www.blabla.com/' and url hold '../images/wow.jpg'. No clue why it works fine in the demo but not in the code I tried... Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can use a `substring`: `var img = IMAGE_PATH + url.substring(3);`. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jdue2eqc/1/). If you need to get a more appropriate help, you must post the whole relevant code.

Comment: Any feedback? Did it finally work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (no jQuery needed):

```
var s = 'http://www.blabla.com/../images/wow.jpg'.replace('../','');
```